# Sub domains using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I have one domain, and want to put all of my scripts there. So that they can be accessed like this: script.mydomain.com, anotherscript.mydomain.com and so on.

Pretty much like google, they have their main www.google.com domain, and for drive they have: drive.google.com.

I didn't find anything related to sub domains in the laravel docs.
Can anyone please explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [route groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) with `domain` key.

> Route groups may also be used to handle sub-domain routing.
>   Sub-domains may be assigned route parameters just like route URIs,
>   allowing you to capture a portion of the sub-domain for usage in your
>   route or controller. The sub-domain may be specified using the domain
>   key on the group attribute array:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: i created a folder in the views directory for each of the subdomains. how can i now add its namespace to the views?